# Tying H Bridge outputs

Tags: h-bridge

When using an H bridge IC such as L293 which has enable inputs, is it possible to tie outputs together such that an 'enabled' output is joined to a 'disabled' output without ill effect? In the system I am thinking of (to do with DCC Train control) there would never be a time when both tied outputs would be enabled but could be a time when neither was enabled. Is this possible? (or harmfull to the IC?)

I am very new to this website so don't know how to add schematic.
However, what I want to do is to use this device to power a point (turnout) section of track in a model railway using DCC. In one position of the turnout I want to power the frog with one output(say the A side) with the other tied output (B side) disabled and then in the other position of the turnout the power comes from the B side with the A side disabled.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this "solution"? Can you post a schematic? (Schematic button on editor toolbar if you want to create one with the relevant bits.)

Comment: If it's a DC system then surely you just want to connect the frog alternately to V+ or COM (common)?

Comment: You can add schematics as images as well.

Answer (score 1):

The 'frog' is that area in the centre of a set of railway points (British) or switch (North American) where the rails intersect. It presents a problem on DC model railways as it can short out the supply when the points are being switched.

[image]

*Figure 1. Frog polarity control. Source: [New Railway Modellers](http://www.newrailwaymodellers.co.uk/electrics-dcc-wiring-a-layout.htm).*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmkLe6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Alternating polarity to each section of track using half H-bridge drivers. 'A' and 'B' are two halves of a H-bridge driving the upper and lower rails of Figure 1. The FROG connection drives the frog.*

The switches of Figure 2 represent the transistors of a semiconductor bridge driver.

> In the system I am thinking of (to do with DCC Train control) there would never be a time when both tied outputs would be enabled but could be a time when neither was enabled. Is this possible? (or harmfull to the IC?)

If you disable the frog before switching the points and then re-enable it you should be fine. No damage will occur. It would be best to have a current limited supply to prevent damage to the H-bridges in the event of a short circuit which could happen due to other reasons anyway.

Some of your concerns are discussed in the New Railway Modellers link above.